# How to run a phylogenetic analysis with non-independent data?

Tags: phylogenetics

These are the facts: I am working with some morphological features. Each trait can have one of the following three states: 0, 1, 2.

State 0 is always independent.

But if there is a trait with state 1, then there must be, in another column of the same row, a state 2 (and vice versa, obviously).

The traits can't be encoded separately because, eg, in the `row_01`, at the `trait_01`, the state 1 is ligated to the `trait_20` with state 2. But in another row (`row_02`), the `trait_01` with state 1 could be ligated to another trait (`trait_33`) with state 2. My data behaves like this because I'm working with morphology in... molecules.

So far, I know that the data of an array in phylogeny must be independent, so I am wondering if any of you know of any way to approach this problem (paper, algorithm, your own propose, etc.).

solving conditions:

- I can't discard the traits with state 1 or 2.

Cheers!

Comment: I am not sure that I understand. If the traits fully determine each other, why are they encoded separately? It might help to see a sample of the data. If traits were even slightly decomposable one might suggest an ordination method (like PCA) to find independent eigentraits, for example http://adn.biol.umontreal.ca/~numericalecology/Reprints/Guenard_et_al_MEE_2013.pdf.

Comment: Since I last looked at this question, the editing appears to have obfuscated it. e.g. `My data behaves like this because I'm working with morphology in... molecules.` what does it mean for data to be "ligated"?